# How to pin a topic in a Google Group?

Tags: google-groups

I can't find the option to "pin" a topic in Google Groups anymore. I somehow was able to before, see the pinned topics in the pic here:

[image: Pinned topics example]

but can't find the option anymore in the 'Actions' dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the image included in the question, the option appears as "Display at the top".

---

**References**
[Create a new topic - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1046523?hl=en)

Comment: So "Display at the top" is equivalent to pinning now?  I tried that out, and it indeed goes to the top, but the Pin icon does not appear like the others...  But so far I'm giving the benefit of the doubt that indeed does achieve "pinning"; I guess if it's displayed at the top always, then that's the whole point at the end of the day...